# Is there a way to make a certain device not need root to access

Tags: usb, python

Apparently you need to be root to access devices through Python. Is there a way to identify a particular USB device and then set it up so I don't need to be root to access it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your user to `dialout` group. This will allow you to access usb devices without root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Device nodes (the files in /dev) are typically created these days by udev.  Udev basically defines a set of rules that control how the devices files are created.  This includes setting the owning user/group.

Devices get different permissions/settings based on their device type.  Check to see if the device you are using is already assigning a non-root group to the node for your device.  If yes, just add your user to that group.

If not, then you should be able to create a rule that will set group and permissions so that the user you are running your python script as will have the require access to the device.